# How to handle failure while delivering content after In App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS app that uses In App Purchase.

It uses a consumable type product which when purchased by a user allows him/her to upload an audio to the server.

Once the InAppPurchase is successful, the data is uploaded to the server.

How do we handle the case when the InAppPurchase is successful but the uploading fails?
We shouldn't make the user buy the product again so I'm storing whether the upload is successful or not in user defaults.

Here is the code

```
SKProduct *productToBuy = //product to buy.
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:productToBuy.productIdentifier] boolValue]) //if the user has already bought the product and it failed to upload, then just try to upload without buying..
{
    NSLog(@"already purchased, uploading");
    [self uploadRecording];
}
else //if not, then make the user purchase and then upload
{
    [[CGInAppPurchaseManager sharedManager] buyProduct:productToBuy withCompletionBlock:^(SKPaymentTransaction *paymentTransaction, BOOL success) {
        if (success)
        {
            [self uploadRecording];
        }
        else
        {
            if (paymentTransaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
            {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled transaction");
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

The uploadRecording code looks like this

```
- (void)uploadRecording
{
    NSURL *urlOfAudio = //url of audio file

    [self.model uploadAdOrDedicationWithTitle:title audioData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlOfAudio] withCompletionBlock:^(id obj, NSInteger errCode, NSString *errorDescription) {
    SKProduct *productToBuy = self.adParams[@"product"];
    if (obj)
    {
        //if its successfully uploaded set false that the user has already bought a product with this identifier
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:productToBuy.productIdentifier];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else
    {
        //when there is an error set true that the user has already bought a product with this identifier
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:productToBuy.productIdentifier];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];                                                

        //show appropriate error message
        //"An error occured while uploading your broadcast. You will not be made to purchase the product again the next time you try to upload a recording for the same product."
    }
  }];
}
```

Is this okay? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should refund, but it isn't possible, so you are stuck with trying the minimize and remedy the problem the best way you can.  Your solution is a remedy that does seem like the least you can do.  Additionally, if there is a way to do some verification to check that the upload is likely to function ahead of the actual upload (using [the Reachability API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) or better still connecting to your server for a quick availability check), then this would minimize the risk of this occurring.